# Finding all possible values of $x, y$ satisfying $\sin^2x + 4 \sin^2y - \sin x - 2\sin y - 2\sin x\sin y + 1 = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I came across this question:

> Find all possible values of $x$, $y$ satisfying:
>
> $$\sin^2x + 4 \sin^2y - \sin x - 2\sin y - 2\sin x \sin y + 1 = 0 \qquad\forall\space x, y \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

I guessed one way would be to write the expression to the left as the sum of three squares:

$$(p\sin x + q)^2 + (u\sin y + v)^2 + (l \sin x + m\sin y)^2 = 0$$

where $p$, $q$, $u$, $v$, $l$, $m$ are real numbers such that the respective coefficients of the term add up as they should. But it appears that those constants wouldn't be simple whole numbers or even numbers which I can get from trial and error methods.

So how do I go about solving such an equation?

Comment: Try $$x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Doesn't work :3

Comment: Aha, then we get $$(\sin(y)-\frac{1}{2})^2=0$$

Comment: Oh wait my bad I put both x and y = pi/2

Comment: $$x=\frac{\pi}{2},y=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Yes that works but how do I find all the possible values of x and y? Arbitrarily setting x to pi/2 and getting y = pi/6 seems almost coincidental for both the values to be so... neat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: With $$a=\sin(x),b=\sin(y)$$ we get
$$a^2+4b^2-a-2b-2ab+1=0$$

Comment: Honestly that's pretty easy to see but now what?

Comment: Solve for $a$ or $b$

Comment: The discriminant is given by$$-(2b-1)^2$$ so $$b=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Can you solve it now?

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: Yes I got it. I didn't realize that you could treat it as an equation in a for a fixed value of b. Thanks, again :)

Comment: No Problem, i'm glad that i could help you!